# How to parse out information from pickle?

Tags: python, deserialization, pickle

I have a program that creates a pickled data file. I am able to unpickle the pickle file, and load it like below.

```
objects = []
with (open(filename, 'rb')) as openfile:
    while True:
        try:
            objects.append(pickle.load(openfile))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

If I type `objects`, it prints out all the data like below:

```
results {
  alternatives {
    transcript: " Scarlett Johansson"
    confidence: 0.980593681335
    words {
      start_time {
        seconds: 11
        nanos: 900000000
      }
      end_time {
        seconds: 12
        nanos: 600000000
      }
      word: "Scarlett"
    }
    words {
      start_time {
        seconds: 12
        nanos: 600000000
      }
      end_time {
        seconds: 12
        nanos: 800000000
      }
      word: "Johansson"
    }
  }
```

But now I don't know how I can like parse out just the information I want. Like I just want to organize the data so that I can extract out just "Scarlett Johansson" and "seconds" of start time and so on. I tried using indexing form and dictionary ie. `objects[0]` or `objects['transcript']` with no avail. If I have an unpickled file like above, what is the trick about extracting just the info I want?

Comment: You don't have to "parse out" the data, it's all already in the `objects` list—just index into that to selectively retrieve its contents.

Comment: You just have to search (iterate) thorugh the available data, probably recursively. To access data you know the location already, try something like e.g. `objects['results']['alternatives']['transcript']`

Comment: @MichaelButscher if I type `objects['results']`it shows `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`. So when I type `type(objects)`, objects is a list? Is it suppose to be correct?

Comment: In the code you assigned a list object, in the output it seemed to be a dictionary. You should start Python programming with something simpler: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: @MichaelButscher omg I did not recognize that objects = []. Thanks so much :)